# Vb.net - Asp.net- How can I GetUserid knowing only the relative user name (or email)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm a novice programmer in vb.net and I don't understand how can I get the user Id knowing only the username (or email) in order to let the user reset his password. Is there someone who can teach me how can I solve this? Thanks in advance! Here's my code, adapted from the Microsoft model.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Imports Owin
Imports System.Security.Principal

Protected Sub Reset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        'probably wrong
        Dim userId As String = User.Identity.GetUserId()
        'runtime error here, id not found.
        Dim resetToken As String = manager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(userId)

        If resetToken IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim newPassword As String = Password.Text

            Dim user = manager.FindById(userId)
            If user Is Nothing Then
                ErrorMessage.Text = "No user found"
                Return
            End If

            Dim result = manager.ResetPassword(userId, resetToken, Password.Text)
            If result.Succeeded Then
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation")
                Return
            End If
            ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()
            Return
        End If

        ErrorMessage.Text = "An error has occurred"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure, it might be that userId from Asp.Identity and the one used by Owin are not the same. Are you calling manager.CreateIdentity() for generating the id?